# Cómo traer datos anidados en Laravel usando Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Mi sistema tiene la entidad carreras, que tiene un array de series, cada serie tiene un array con sus competidores y resultados, entonces.. cuando hago un get de carreras obtengo esto:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "id_categoria": 3,
    "distancia": "13",
    "sentido": "circular",
    "circuito": "oblicuo",
    "tipo_carrera": "n/e",
    "updated_at": null,
    "created_at": "2020-07-22T17:49:44.000000Z",
    "series": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "id_carrera": 1,
            "depende_de": null,
            "updated_at": "2020-07-22T17:54:59.000000Z",
            "created_at": "2020-07-22T17:50:18.000000Z"
        }
    ],
}
```

pero necesito que el array de series me venga con el array de resultados incluidos, cómo puedo hacerlo?
Actualmente el get del controlador está así:

```
  public function index()
    {
        return Carrera::with('series')->get();
    }
```

Comment: Podrías mostrar tus `Model` (Carrera, Serie y Resultados)

Comment: Carrera::with('series.resultados')->get();